# Intellij spring boot integration

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, spring-boot

For some reason **Intellij 13.1.3** doesn't detect the spring boot beans. Spring boot version is **1.1.1-Release**. When i try to inject ObjectMapper in some component i get an error in the IDE "No bean of type ObjectMapper defined", however the application compiles and runs just fine and the ObjectMapper beans is visible in the /beans json.

I have added my application-context and my Application.java files to a spring facet and the IDE recognizes all my other beans that I manually defined, it just ignores the ones that come with Spring boot **@EnableAutoConfiguration**. Any idea how to solve that since its kinda tedious not to have the correct linking in the IDE and get errors all over the place. I would assume thats a common issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Boot is not supported yet, please watch http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-119230

Answer (score 2):

As an update for this answer:  IntelliJ now supports Spring Boot.  Must be at least R14.  R15 is including some more integration.